Finding negative cycles using the Bellman-Ford algorithm and a source node
I'm exploring the Bellman-Ford algorithm to detect and track negative cycles (a collection of ncycle that we can see in the implementation).
I'm wondering if the algorithm finds the same collection regardless of the source node when we can reach any node from any other node.

What do you mean by the "set" of negative cycles that Bellman-Ford finds?  I suggest you [edit] your question to make it more precise.  There might be a ton of negative cycles, and any particular execution of Bellman-Ford might reveal only one of those cycles.

@D.W. I added the algorithm I refer to.

I know what the Bellman-Ford algorithm is.  That doesn't help.  What is the motivation for this question?  In what context did you encounter it?  I don't understand what you mean by "a collection of ncycle" - perhaps you are referring to a specific implementation, but some context seems to be missing.

Have you checked the link? It describes said implementation (along with ncycle we get for every edge).

Once you reach a vertex in any cycle, traversing from it in either forward or backward direction will eventually reveal the entire cycle.

Depending on the implementation, that is what you do in cases where multiple negative cycles are present, which might give a different answer (if only the first negative cycle encountered from a given source vertex is reported).

I believe there might be some confusion here. ncycle is simply a linked list (presumably, or any ordered set of elements) that contains all vertices of some negative-weight cycle in the graph (i.e. a cycle where the sum of all weights is below $0$). It is not the set of all negative-weight cycles in the graph.

@ZiadIsmailiAlaoui I don't mean all possible negative cycles. What I mean are negative cycles that are found by the algorithm. So, if we have a source s_1 and the algorithm returns cycles_1, and then we have a source s_2 != s_1 and the algorithm returns cycles_2, we have cycles_1 == cycles_2.
@codeR I don't know if it narrows down the cases, but we talk about the algorithm we have under that link.

Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it is clear and reads well and self-contained for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Our mission is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, in the format of questions and answers, and we don't want crucial clarifications to be buried in a comment thread.

Your question is unclear since it is not explicit what a "collection of ncycle" means. I believe you are asking whether the Wikipedia implementation of the Bellman-Ford algorithm finds the same negative-weight cycle (assuming there is one) regardless of which source vertex we pick in the final depth-first search (DFS) when the input graph is strongly connected (i.e. for any pair of vertices $u,v$, there exist directed paths from $u$ to $v$ and $v$ to $u$).
The answer is "no." Consider the following graph.

As you can observe, it is strongly connected; you can pick any pair of distinct vertices $u,v$ and find a path from $u$ to $v$. Yet, picking vertex 1 as a source for the final negative-weight cycle detection yields the cycle 1, 2, 3, while picking vertex 4 as a source yields 4, 5, 6.

Will the answer change if we have a complete digraph?

No, it will not. Even in the case of a complete digraph, multiple disjoint negative-weight cycles are possible.
